# identifying object name by property value

Tags: javascript

I have an object for a given verb such as...

```
var schlafen = {
    ger: "schlafen",
    eng: "sleep",
    stem: "schlaf",
    pp: "geschlafen",
    sp: "schlief",
    type: "verb",
    reflexive: false
};
```

I would like to be able to identify and reference the object and it's properties when my script comes across an instance of one of it's properties such as...

```
var example = "geschlafen";
```

I am trying to get to the object itself from only one of it's properties so that I can then use another one of it's properties(for example, the "type" property) to identify an instance of "geschlafen" as a verb.

Comment: If you want to “get to the object itself”, I assume you have more objects of the same type, for different words? Well, you will have to loop through all of them, so that you can check their individual properties for whether there is one with the value `geschlafen` …

Comment: If you have a list of all of the possible objects, you can loop through each object's properties to find a match.  But there's no way to go in the other direction.  What I would do is do that loop (through all of the objects) once, and make a giant object that goes in the other direction (i.e. it has a property for each value in any of the objects, whose value is the source object) and use that to search.

Comment: Thanks guys.  That was what I was afraid of.  Seems like a slow as hell process with a theoretical dictionary of hundreds of verbs.

Comment: If I really needed to do this kind of thing in javascript (find full word information based on a single inflection of the word), I would write a server-side web service to handle it, and then call the web service using AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create an index object that maps the values back to the associated object, for example:

```
var index = {};
function indexObject(obj) {
    var keys = ['ger', 'eng', 'stem', 'pp', 'sp'];
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (obj[keys[i]]) {
            index[obj[keys[i]]] = obj;
        }
    }
}

// index your schlafen object (you would also want to do this for other objects)
indexObject(schlafen);

var example = "geschlafen";

// lookup the object using your index
var obj = index[example];

// make sure we got the correct object back (should log 'true')
console.log(obj === schlafen);
```

Comment: Thanks sir.  This is pretty much an implementation of what JacobM suggested no?